# Regex comparison in Oracle between 2 varchar columns (from different tables)

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to find a way to capture relevant errors from oracle alertlog. I have one table (ORA_BLACKLIST) with column values as below (these are the values which I want to ignore from
V$DIAG_ALERT_EXT)

Below are sample data in ORA_BLACKLIST table. This table can grow based on additional error to ignore from alertlog.

```
ORA-07445%[kkqctdrvJPPD
ORA-07445%[kxsPurgeCursor
ORA-01013%
ORA-27037%
ORA-01110
ORA-2154
```

V$DIAG_ALERT_EXT contains a MESSAGE_TEXT column which contains sample text like below.

```
ORA-01013: user requested cancel of current operation
ORA-07445: exception encountered: core dump [kxtogboh()+22] [SIGSEGV] [ADDR:0x87] [PC:0x12292A56]
ORA-07445: exception encountered: core dump [java_util_HashMap__get()] [SIGSEGV]
ORA-00600: internal error code arguments: [qercoRopRowsets:anumrows]
```

I want to write a query something like below to ignore the black listed errors and only capture relevant info like below.

select
dae.instance_id,
dae.container_name,
err_count,
dae.message_level
from
ORA_BLACKLIST ob,
V$DIAG_ALERT_EXT dae
where

group by .....;

Can someone suggest a way or sample code to achieve it?

I should have provided the exact contents of blacklist table. It currently contains some regex (perl) and I want to convert it to oracle like regex and compare with v$diag_alert_ext message_text column. Below are sample perl regex in my blacklist table.

ORA-0(,|$| )
ORA-48913
ORA-00060
ORA-609(,|$| )
ORA-65011
ORA-65020 ORA-31(,|$| )
ORA-7452 ORA-959(,|$| )
ORA-3136(,|)|$| )
ORA-07445.*[kkqctdrvJPPD
ORA-07445.*[kxsPurgeCursor –

Answer (score 1):

Your `blacklist` table looks like `like` patterns, not regular expressions.

You can write a query like this:

```
select dae.* -- or whatever columns you want
from V$DIAG_ALERT_EXT dae
where not exists (select 1
                  from ORA_BLACKLIST ob
                  where dae.message_text like ob.<column name>
                 );
```

This will not have particularly good performance if the tables are large.

Comment: @pritiprabhasahoo Please add new information about your question in an "update" section of a post. Your comment makes it more confusing for reader to understand the whole. Consider make an update and delete a comment.